# Installing Ubuntu with SSD in a Toshiba Satellite L50-B-137 (PSKT4E)

Tags: uefi, ssd, toshiba

I have recently upgraded the BIOS in my Toshiba Satellite L50-B-137 (PSKT4E) to the latest (Version 2.00) and I am trying to install Linux Ubuntu on a brand new OCZ ARC 100 SSD drive (480GB).

I am getting so far with the installation then receiving the error ***'the ext4 file system creation in partition 1 (0,0,0)(sda) failed'***. Various forums have suggested that I need to enable AHCI but this option is not available in the BIOS.

The options that I have are *"CSM Boot"* or *"UEFI Boot"* I have checked with OCZ and the SSD drive itself does support Linux. I've tried installing both version 14.04 and also version 15.04.

I did have 14.04 working perfectly fine with a normal SATA hard drive before so it must be the new drive somehow.

Any help would be appreciated guys.

Thanks

Comment: UEFI and CSM are totally different settings to drive configuration/mount which is AHCI, RAID, very old IDE, and maybe others. Will Windows be on drive also? If you use UEFI drive must then be gpt partitioned. IF only Ubuntu you can have gpt partitioning and boot in UEFI or CSM/BIOS mode. But if MBR partitioned it can only boot in BIOS/CSM Mode. Drive settings may be on different UEFI configuration screen than boot settings. Recheck UEFI settings.

Comment: It's possible your disk is just plain defective. You might try doing the filesystem creation at the command line, as in `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda1` . (Note that this assumes `/dev/sda1` exists and is the right partition; it's conceivable that it's failing at the partitioning stage of the task, not at filesystem creation.) Command-line tools often return more verbose error messages than GUI tools, and in this case greater verbosity is required to figure out what's going wrong.